# How to change gfortran version on fedora37

Tags: fedora

I have a server with fedora 37, which has gcc and gfortran installed (version 12). There is a program I need compile with gfortran-9, however, I use the *yum search all gfortran* and didn't find specific version. Is there only one way to install gfrotran-9 from the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way here is simply using `podman run -i -t --rm -v /path/to/fortran/src:/SRC:Z centos:7` to run a container of an operating system that still ships the older gfortran (and I took a wild guess and assumed centos:7 might), and then build in there.

Other than that, gfortran is somewhat conservative, so you might just have to find the right compiler flags to make your old code build with modern gfortran.

Later addendum: `centos:7` is too old, but `fedora:31` works, it has gfortram 9.3.1.